# Is there a way to connect Cloud SQL from tools like SQL YOG if i have a firewall in Office?

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I am able to connect Cloud SQL using SQL Yog using my internet data card as it provides a unique IP address for the handshake process . But from office i cannot connect as it has a firewall. And when the IP address i receive is of my firewall instead of my host. Is there a better way to connect Cloud Sql from office where firewall IP restricts the handshake process

Comment: maybe a vpn connection could help you ... question who restricts the connection your office admistrator or the isp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what SQL Yog is, but one other option is to create a Google Compute Engine instance. You can then connect from your workstation to the GCE instance, and then connect to Cloud SQL from within that instance.